# Nginx Request Time Latency Spikes

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as reverse proxy to my backend (Java app with Spring boot). In overall (avg, p50, p90, p95, p99 latencies) it performs well. But time to time, I see latency spikes around 100-200 milliseconds. When I enabled the access logs, I see that upstream response time (`upstream_response_time`) is very low even though request time (`request_time`) is high. For example,

```
[25/Apr/2020:18:28:17 +0000] "XXX" XXX - request="POST /v1/composite-monitoring-data HTTP/1.1" status=429 request_time=0.081 trace_id="Root=1-5ea48141-2f8e07a4c7c71a1360d9c5f5" request_length=9864 bytes_sent=979 body_bytes_sent=623 upstream_addr=127.0.0.1:5000 upstream_status=429 upstream_response_time=0.004 upstream_connect_time=0.000 upstream_header_time=0.004 user_agent="okhttp/3.10.0" current_time_msec=1587839297.256
...
[25/Apr/2020:18:28:17 +0000] "XXX" XXX - request="POST /v1/composite-monitoring-data HTTP/1.1" status=429 request_time=0.084 trace_id="Root=1-5ea48141-51f0d12a6f7c4b0651f6ef42" request_length=20534 bytes_sent=979 body_bytes_sent=623 upstream_addr=127.0.0.1:5000 upstream_status=429 upstream_response_time=0.000 upstream_connect_time=0.000 upstream_header_time=0.000 user_agent="okhttp/3.10.0" current_time_msec=1587839297.278
```

Also here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
user nginx;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 32768;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
    use                 epoll;
    multi_accept        on;
}

http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    default_type application/json;

    sendfile    on;
    tcp_nopush  off;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout       300;
    keepalive_requests      10000;

    client_body_timeout     15;
    client_header_timeout   15;
    client_body_buffer_size 4m;
    client_max_body_size    4m;

    log_format  main    '[$time_local] "$http_x_forwarded_for" $remote_addr - '
                        'request="$request" status=$status request_time=$request_time trace_id="$http_x_amzn_trace_id" '
                        'request_length=$request_length bytes_sent=$bytes_sent body_bytes_sent=$body_bytes_sent '
                        'upstream_addr=$upstream_addr '
                        'upstream_status=$upstream_status '
                        'upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time '
                        'upstream_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time '
                        'upstream_header_time=$upstream_header_time '
                        'user_agent="$http_user_agent" '
                        'current_time_msec=$msec';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    upstream http_backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;

        keepalive 1024;
    }

    server {

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name _ localhost;

        location /v1 {
            proxy_pass                          http://http_backend/v1;
            proxy_set_header Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Request-Start    $msec;
            proxy_set_header Connection         "";
            proxy_http_version                  1.1;

            keepalive_timeout       300;
            keepalive_requests      10000;
        }

        location /ping {
            proxy_pass                          http://http_backend/ping;
        }

    }

}
```

What might cause this big difference between the request time and upstream response time? Is there anything I need to configure and not configured properly?

Comment: I am having a very similar issue, were you ever able to figure this out?